# Skype receiving weird strings

Tags: skype

My friend is always receiving weird strings whenever I try to message her on Skype:

> skype:?cha t&blob =cfNUz15ws Y9T-4T6e6I TrJTMj4Q0I 7VDDJ-dvFN UDtHVqImE1 FiYGsH-xEE uReSm

She is on a Mac and the language is set to French.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What your friend is getting looks like a [Skype Chat Join Link](http://incomeassurance.com/blog/skype-chat-join-links/).

Could you elaborate please more about how you are sending the message, whether you do manage to message other people in this way except your friend, and whether your friend can get messages normally from other people.

If it is only one person that is having the problem, maybe reinstalling Skype can fix it.

Comment: I can message other people perfectly, but my friend's messaging doesn't work

Comment: Are you using IM: Do you just click on the contact, type the message at the bottom and then Send?